# Get name product By ID with $select->joinLeft()

Tags: php, sql, magento, magento-1.8

I have a module that lists the customers for each product, ie when access a product in admin, he has a list of people who bought that product, in the same Sales grid style.

This Grid, I want to display the name and SKU "only" of the product concerned. Within the Grid, the id of the product is in the variable $ id

I am using the code below, but it returns all the application products and not only the product ID X

```
    $select = $orders->getSelect();
    $select->joinLeft('sales_flat_order_item', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_item.order_id', 
        array(
        'skus' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(sales_flat_order_item.sku SEPARATOR ", ")'),
        'qty_ordered' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(sales_flat_order_item.qty_ordered SEPARATOR ", ")'),
        )
        );

        $select->group('main_table.entity_id');
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the working code, so it only displays the name and SKU of the product that is being viewed.

```
   $select = $orders->getSelect();
  $select->joinLeft('sales_flat_order_item', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_item.order_id AND sales_flat_order_item.product_id = ' . $id, 
        array(
        'skus' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(sales_flat_order_item.sku SEPARATOR ", ")'),
        'qty_ordered' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(sales_flat_order_item.qty_ordered SEPARATOR ", ")'),
        )
        );
```

Thanks @scrowler

Comment: `main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_item.order_id` is your join condition? You need to add the ID in, e.g. `main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_item.order_id AND sales_flat_order_item.product_id = ' . $id` (not tested)

Comment: No problem - you should take that UPDATE out of your question and post it as an answer instead

Comment: @scrowler I realized that when buying more than one unit, it does the sum, always displays 1 as a result, know why?

Comment: Because you're concatenating the quantities together by comma. Do array sum or explode and pass in comma and the string for quantity